# wait_for_service in rosjava?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a rosjava equivalent to the python wait_for_service() call?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12585/wait_for_service-in-rosjava?/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is not. Please file a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2